# Invalid Argument error is shown on Google Cloud Storage files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using the web interface, I am trying to make public files that were uploaded and each time I click the checkbox I immediately get the error "Invalid Argument" and the box unchecks.

This also happens while trying to uncheck files already uploaded and public.

I'm not certain if something happened to my account or if this is a service problem for the site but we're in a major jame because of this. Essentially Cloud storage is unusable at this stage.

Comment: There is a known issue currently being investigated around setting object ACLs via the web user interface and the JSON interface that you are most likely affected by. In the meanwhile, the gsutil tool and the XML interface are unaffected, and you can use those to set files to publicly viewable. I will provide a further update when the issue is resolved. See https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil for more on how to use gsutil.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. If you are still experiencing a problem making a file public, please contact gs-team@google.com.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the web user interface and the JSON interface affecting setting ACLs on objects. That problem has been resolved, and all interfaces should be working correctly now.